# DataMongoTest load Interceptors

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I got a DataMongoTest which is executing fine but it does not load the interceptors that are configured

```
@Configuration
public class EntityInterceptors extends AbstractMongoEventListener<Entity> { ... }

@DataMongoTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles({"default", "test"})
public class MongoTest {

  @Autowired
  private DataRepository repo;
  ... 
}
```

The repository gets correctly wired and is accessible in the tests. Its not an embedded DB but an external test db that gets cleaned up before tests.

If I execute this inside a application environment the interceptors all load. But they don't load inside the test class. How can I add the class to the execution context without using it as `SpringBootTest`where all the other unneded stuff is also loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataMongoTest is not enough to run for this:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
// Add Config and all dependent Interceptors
@SpringBootTest(classes = {
    InterceptorConfig.class,
    TopEntityInterceptor.class,
    CascadedEntityInterceptor.class
})
// MONGO INIT
@ImportAutoConfiguration
@AutoConfigurationPackage
@AutoConfigureDataMongo
@ActiveProfiles({"default", "test"})
class InterceptorTest {
  @Autowired TopEnitityRepository repo;
}
```

You can now use the repo and check if the interceptors did their job after persisting and if interceptors also cascade.